# How to replace a sting using python

Tags: python

I want to replace a string ('None') with **NULL** without quote.

For example:

```
data  = ('a','None','1','None')
```

And desired result:

```
result = "'a', NULL, '1', NULL"
```

Is there a way to get the expected result? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is `NULL`? is this a variable in your code (it does not exist in python)? Or did you mean `None`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta agreed, but the question changed.  in the first question it wasn't a string but a tuple with a `NULL` symbol in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to build the resulting string:

```
data  = ('a','None','1','None')
t = ', '.join('NULL' if t == 'None' else repr(t) for t in data)
```

`t` is then the string `"'a', NULL, '1', NULL"`.

But I really cannot imagine a real world use case for that...

Comment: This answer works for me. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not a valid keyword in Python. Instead, you use `None`. In addition, you cannot modify a Tuple.

If you are using a list, however;

```py
data[1] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator comprehension along with the `tuple()` function:

```
data = ('a', 'None', '1', 'None')

# For NULL without quotes
result = tuple(el if el is not 'None' else NULL for el in data)

# 'NULL' with quotes
result = tuple(el if el is not 'None' else 'NULL' for el in data)
```

If you want your final result to be a comma-seperated string of values, use this:

```
# Replace 'NULL' with NULL if you want to reference the variable
new_result = ', '.join(el if el is not 'None' else 'NULL' for el in data)
```